# How to put line break on Three state work flow body in SP2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online

How to put line break on Three state work flow body in SP2010 ?

Is it possible to put line break on email body of three state work flow. If yes how can I do that?.

I tried below:

```
<<br>>,/t,/n,/t/n
```

etc but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `%0D%0A` instead of `/n`